# SubSonic 2.1 help needed c#

Tags: c#, sql, subsonic, count

I got the following setup for my database:

```
Category Table (Fields: CategoryID(PK), Title);

Menu Table (Fields: MenuID(PK) CategoryID(FK), Title);

Page Table (Fields PageID(PK), MenuID(FK), Title, Content, CreatedOn);
```

Now for one page I want to know how many Pages a particular category holds.
I have no clue how to make such query with SubSonic.
The way I'm doing it now is like this:

```
int count = 0;
DAL.MenuCollection coll = new DAL.MenuCollection().WHERE(DAL.ObjectMenu.Columns.CategoryID, _catid);

foreach(DAL.Menu item in coll)
{

  DAL.PageCollection collTemp = new DAL.PageCollection().WHERE(DAL.Page.Columns.MenuID, _menuid);
  count+= collTemp.Count;

}
```

This will work but isn't there a better way to write it within a single statement? This looks kinda bad I think,

I Hope someone can point me in the right direction.
Thank you for reading
Kind regard,s
Mark

Answer (score 1):

You need some joins and then some post-retrieval work. If you want to do this all at once, load up a query with what you need to know using joins and then roll a loop over it, organizing it as you need to.

Here's more on joins and queries in general:
http://www.subsonicproject.com/docs/Simple_Query_Tool

Comment: Since i cant compare to rob i will just add my answer as a comment , you could always create it as a view and then just count the number of lines returned